# Bayes spam filtering - count probability that word occurs in spam / ham

Tags: filter, spam, bayesian

Let's say that I have two data sets - examples of spam messages and ham messages (for example 1000 spam messages and 800 ham messages).

The word "free" occurs in 700 spam messages and in 200 ham messages. **But in some messages occurs more times. Does that matter?**

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: it depends.  You didn't say how often that happens.

If you have 1000 messages and the word "free" occurs in 900 of them then it seems like it is common (appearing in 90% of all messages).  If, however, the word infrequently occurs more than once in a message, that is more useful.  Singling out a particular word is unlikely to be helpful early in your project.

Look up tf-idf (term frequency, inverse document frequency).  Here the idea is that you weight words more heavily when they appear multiple times in a document but less heavily when they appear in a lot of documents.

Also, based on your numbers, you have a what is known as a class imbalance.  A classifier that simply guessed spam 100% of the time would do very well with your example data - it would be right at least 70% of the time.